# Cómo decir "scofflaw" en español

Tags: traducción, modismos, terminología

En inglés tenemos la palabra ***scofflaw***:

> a contemptuous law violator

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scofflaw)

Usualmente aplica a pilotos de carros y coches que acumulan muchas multas y remisiones sin pagarlas.

¿Cuál es la palabra exacta para hablar con la agencia de seguros o la policía?

Comment: Encontré en http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/scofflaw.php: infractor de la ley, maleante, malandro, cábula, chusmero.  Yo iba a decir *mal actor*.

Answer (score 3):

Para hablar con la policía o con aseguradoras, si necesitas referirte a una persona que constantemente incumple la ley, acumulando sanciones, yo usaría:

> **[reincidente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VmZDhbD)**
>
> 1. adj. Que reincide o ha reincidido. U. t. c. s.

Que viene de:

> **[reincidir](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VmcrvJ1)**
>
> De *re-* e *incidir*<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 1. intr. Volver a caer o incurrir en un error, falta o delito.

Por tanto, un *reincidente* es aquel que incurre repetidamente en faltas o delitos. Sin embargo, esto no deja claro que deje las multas sin pagar, porque se puede ser un reincidente aun pagando las multas. No encuentro pues ninguna palabra que por sí sola implique todo lo que *scofflaw* conlleva, tal vez lo más corto sería ***reincidente [moroso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Pr9j9r6)*** (que se retrasa en el pago de las deudas).